# Longest Common Subsequence with Restricted Number of Substring Parts

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, computer-science

Recently I am learning Dynamic Programming (DP) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASoaQq66foQ&ab_channel=BackToBackSWE) shows building up the DP table to get the Longest Common Subsequence (lcs).

What would this table be if there is another parameter m that restricts the number of substring parts? For example, suppose we have a="xxyzxyz" and b="xyz" and we are only allowed to break the substrings to only 2 parts, so m=2. And the result generates the maximum number of combination that the substrings can place in the string.

In this case, we have the following,

[x]xyx[yz]

x[x]yx[yz]

xxy[x][yz]

x[xy]x[z]

Note that the letters inside [] are considered 1 part, so we have 2 []'s in accordance with m=2. So in this case, the result is 4.

I am wondering how I can build up my DP table. Could this one by a 3-D instead of the traditional a-b 2-D DP table? My guess is the DP equation is lcs(a, b, m) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please rewrite your question so that it can be understood by someone who hasn't watched that video?

Comment: Why is `xxy[xy][z]` not counted in the example solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursion - Longest Common Subsequence with Restriction on N number of substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69578720/recursion-longest-common-subsequence-with-restriction-on-n-number-of-substring)

Comment: Hi Sir, yes, xxy[xy][z] is also correct, and I also posted there, but my task is to get the DP in iterative algorithm instead of recursion. In that thread, the recursion is using i+1 and j+1 which means I am unable to get out an iterative case.