# Recursion - Longest Common Subsequence with Restriction on N number of substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am really stuck on a question that I am given a String input S, another String input U that represent the entire substring and a non-negative int number m. The method is lcs(S, U, m).

For example: Let S="aabacaab", U="aab", and m=2. Then we have the following substring combinations:

```
[a][ab]acaab

[a]abaca[ab]

a[a]baca[ab]

aab[a]ca[ab]

aabac[a][ab]

[aa][b]acaab

[aa]bacaa[b]

aabac[aa][b]
```

So `lcs(S, U, m)` returns `8` as we have 8 different combinations of substrings of U with the restriction of `m` number of substrings.

My initial thinking is to compare the first character of `S` with the first character of `U` and recurse down by shortening both `S` and `U`. However, due to `m`, I am unable to determine how `m` should be reduced as the shortened `S` and `U` don't have any reference to the previous state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with dynamic programming on strings, the answer to "What should my subproblems be" is often prefixes, suffixes, or substrings.

From your final note, you've correctly identified that we can solve the original problem by solving the problem on suffixes. We also know that our subproblem has to know the number of pieces we have left to use. At this point, we can guess what the subproblems are and try to define a formula.

We can let `f(i,j,k)` be the number of ways to match the last `j` letters of `U` using the last `i` letters of `S` into exactly `k` substrings. What are the edge cases? If `j` and `k` are both 0, we have nothing to do; there's 1 way to do nothing. If `i<j` we cannot match the `j` letters, and if `j<k` we cannot split the `j` letters into enough pieces.

Finally, you have to define the main recursion. First, we can skip this letter of `S`, which gives `f(i-1,j,k)` as a summand. Now, let `Match-Length(i,j)` be the number of consecutive places at the start of `S[-i:]` that match `U[-j:]`. We need to add on all the possible matches: for every length `l`, `1 <= l <= Match-Length(i,j)`, we have to add `f(i-l, j-l, k-1)`. This covers all cases.

Edit: User qouify has posted a better solution. A direct translation of this DP formula runs in time `O(|S| |U|^2 m)`, while theirs runs in `O(|S| |U| m)`. My formula can be modified to match that run-time, but you need to compute prefix sums so that each sum of `f(i-l, j-l, k-1)` can be found in `O(1)` time after preprocessing and memoization.

Comment: Hi kcsquared, could you please explain this part "Now, let Match-Length(i,j) be the number of consecutive places at the start of S[-i:] that match U[-j:]. We need to add on all the possible matches: for every length l, 1 <= l <= Match-Length(i,j), we have to add f(i-l, j-l, k-1). All that's left is to check that this covers all cases."  a bit more with examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To shorten `m`, you will have to look at the current letters in `S`
and `U`.  If both letters are the same you have two considers two (non
exclusive) situations:

- you are currently matching a sub-string of `S` (which means, using
  your notations, that you have opened a string, like `[aa...`) in
  which case you can continue that matching
- you still have a strictly positive number of sub-strings to match in
  which case you can start a new matching (whatever you are currently
  matching a string or not)

For that, you will need an additional parameter for your recursion
which specifies if you are currently matching a sub-string.

The base case indicating that you have found a match to your problem
is when you have reached the end of `U` and `m` is equal to `0`.

Here is the code that implements this solution (note that the function handles list of letters rather than strings):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import functools

def lcs(s, u, m) -> int:

    # recursive function
    #   i: index in list s
    #   j: index in list j
    #   m: number of sub-strings to find
    #   match: are we currently matching a sub-string or not?
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=10000)  #  cache the result of our function
    def loop(i, j, m, match) -> int:
        # base cases
        if j >= len(u):  # end of u reached => no more letter to look for
            if m == 0: # check if have found our m sub-strings
                return 1
            return 0
        if i >= len(s):  # end of s reached and still letter to look for 
            return 0

        result = loop(i + 1, j, m, False)  # skip the current letter

        # letter in s and u are the same (we will move both i and j)
        if s[i] == u[j]:
            if match:  # we are currently matching a sub-string => continue
                result += loop(i + 1, j + 1, m, True)
            if m > 0:  # we can start a new sub-string
                result += loop(i + 1, j + 1, m - 1, True)
        return result

    return loop(0, 0, m, False)

print(lcs(list("aabacaab"), list("aab"), 2))
```

Comment: Hi qouify, thank you for your input and I have fully understood your solution. For dynamic programming table build-up, I have the following code in pseudo, could you check if it is right? N is the 3D chart I am trying to build for Dynamic Programming's iteration.

Comment: def lcs(s, u, m):
 for i in [1, 2, …, len(s)]:
  N[0, a, 0] = 0
 for j in [1, 2, …, len(u)]:
  N[b, 0, 0] = 0
  for k in [1, 2, …, m]:
  N[0, 0, c] = 0
 for i in [1, 2, …, len(s)]:
  for j in [1, 2, …, len(u)]:
   for k in [1, 2, …, m]:
    if s[i] equals u[j] and N[i][j][k] is true:
     N[i][j][k] = N[i][j][k] + N[i+1][j+1][k]
    if s[i] equals u[j] and N[i][j][k] > 0:
     N[i][j][k] = N[i][j][k] + N[i+1][j+1][k-1]

Comment: I only have a question. When converting from Recursion to Dynamic Programming, I thought the current value builds on the previous value(s), so how does it work in Dynamic Programming's iterative code? In our case, we haev i+1 and j+1, shouldn't they be i-1 and j-1? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLu I'm not familiar with dynamic programming.  But can you post your pseudo-code in the question rather than in the comments?

Comment: Hi qouify, I have posted in the reply. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinLu Mmm... I don't see it.  Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: hi, my posted comment is hidden for unknown reason, here is the link to my comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eAeh_GVOhsItjiDIR4pk39bMKjm0RNbGnoC8H6tfb5Q/edit?usp=sharing